# Manual symbol index without number but still in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to create a manual symbol index. I dont want a number for the symbol index using \section*{}. But I want the symbol index to appear in the table of contents (toc) without a number number.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section with numbering}

\section*{Symbol index}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `scrartcl` you can use `\addsec` instead `\section*` to get an unnumbered section with TOC entry.

Comment: Thank you alot! That was exactly what I was looking for :).